# Repo Commands Hang Cyanogenmod

Tags: android, git, cyanogenmod, repo

I am building the cyanogenmod ROM and kernel from source. I downloaded repo successfully, and was able to run "repo init" and "repo sync" successfully. I build my rom and kernel and flashed them successfully. I have recently begun making slight changes to the kernel, just adding a single line to the touch drivers that prints to the kernel message log. I also made some minor configuration changes. I wanted to roll back these changes, and used the command "repo forall -c "git reset"". This command hung for about twenty minutes until I ended it. Behavior is similar for the repo status command. Why is repo hanging?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you proven that the command isn't running and it is taking a lot of CPU during the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new directory and reinitialized repo here.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.0
```

I then created a new branch for my edits.

```
repo start editsbranch .
```

The dot signals to only create this new branch in the current project. Then I checked the repo status, and the comamnd worked!

```
repo status .
```

I am unsure of the exact nature of the problem, but it may have been very computationally expensive to check the status of all the github repositories that repo controls. The usage of the . makes the status command much faster to execute, because it only checks the status of the current project.